# Standard t-distribution on n-degrees of freedom: $T=\frac{X}{\sqrt{Y/n}}$, $S=Y$ how are these selected

Tags: probability

[image]

---

What I don't understand here is how did $T, S$ get selected?

Also, I believe here they are using a change of variable like:

$$(Y_1, Y_2) = T(X_1, X_2)$$

Where $T$ is differentiable and invertible such that:

$$X_1 = T_1^{-1}(Y_1, T_2)$$

and $$X_2 = T_2^{-1}(Y_1, Y_2)$$

Then $J(y_1, y_2)$ is the jacobian transformation ... etc ...

---

In the context of this question, I am also confused whats $T$ & $S$, I thought there was only 1 transformation function?

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I understand ...

In the context of this question, $T$ is the 1st RV $Y_1$ in the defination and $S$ is the 2nd RV $Y_2$. Then they computed the inverse like:

$$M^{-1}_X (T,S) = (\text{make X subject}) = T\sqrt{\frac{s}{n}}$$

$$M^{-1}_Y (T, S) = (\text{make Y subject}) = S$$

Then the jacobian is:

$$J(t, s) = \left|
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\delta M_X^{-1}}{\delta t} & \frac{\delta M_Y^{-1}}{\delta t} \\
\frac{\delta M_X^{-1}}{\delta s} & \frac{\delta M_Y^{-1}}{\delta s}
\end{array}
\right|$$